# Python - compound interest calculation issue - cs1301 edx extra practice 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem I can't manage to solve:

Find "How much do I need to invest to have a certain amount by a certain year?" For example, "How much do I need to invest to have $50,000 in 5 years at 5% (0.05) interest?"

Mathematically, the formula for this is:
goal / e ^ (rate * number of years) = principal

Add some code below that will print the amount of principal
needed to reach the given savings goal within the number of years and interest rate specified.

my solution is:

```
import math

goal = float(goal)
years = float(rate)
rate = rate

principal = goal / (math.e ** (rate * years))
rounded_principal = round(principal, 2)
print(rounded_principal)
```

it should print 38940.04 but instead it prints 49875.16. If i use goal = 200, rate 0.1 and years 1, it returns 198.01 when it should return 180.97

I tried turning the rate into a percentage again by multiplying by 100, adding and deleting parenthesis, tried using a formula found online, not rounding the result, and making e be its pure number (to like 15 decimals).

Comment: years = float(years) should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using rate instead of years for the year.

```
goal = float(goal)
years = float(rate) <-- Here
rate = rate
```